# Command output(stdout,stderr) not redirected to pipe

Tags: c, linux, tty, ioctl

I have a trouble with redirection of `stdout` and `stderr` from proprietary binary.

After some "reverse engineering" with strace tool I have found strange ioctl-call on stdout descriptor.

Can anyone explain me what means that calls?

```
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
```

Comment: does it also make this call when piped? it might be testing to see if STDIN an STDOUT are on a tty.

Comment: It's called, but if process are piped ioctl returns "= -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)" (istead "= 0") and after that writes to stdout not occurs...
Well, thanks, now I understand whats going on.
Can I cheat procces or with any other trick redirect output to file?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing strange with it. It just gets terminal parameters - i.e. parameters of `/dev/pts/X` device coming from `xterm` you running.

From man page of `tcgetattr()` (which is same as `TCGETS`, see `man tty_ioctl`):

> tcgetattr()  gets  the parameters associated with the object referred by fd and stores them in the termios structure referenced by termios_p.  This function may be invoked from a background process; however, the terminal attributes may be subsequently changed by a foreground process.

Comment: I still don't understand, how it affect to std-streams? If I understand correctly, it's only get params from tty

Comment: Can you get me more info about third ioctl param?

Comment: @Dcow, Yes it gets `tty` parameters. Third parameter in `ioctl` call is ioctl-dependent. In case of `TCGETS` ioctl it is `termios` structure that contains various flags describing terminal: in your case its _38400_ is speed in bits/s,  _echo_ means that tty shows input characters, etc.